# How to recover moved (cut) files from a disk?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

I have a PC with two hardrives, in one I have Windows 7 installed, on the other I have a hackintosh; Snow Leopard to be more specific.

Recently (yesterday) I had a disaster with one of my disk partitions while playing with hackintosh.
I screwed the `C:` partition where Windows 7 was installed, corrupting the MFT and with it all my files.

A week ago I made a "backup" of some of those files to the second partition; `D:`, and did a reinstall of Windows on `C:`, afer install I moved backed files to `C:`.
The thing is `C:` is gone and there is no way to recover that files; but what about `D:`? What happens when we move/cut files?

Again, `C:` is unrecoverable, I tried using GetDataBack and got no luck.

Comment: Did you try GetDataBack on D: or only on C:?

Comment: I tried GetDataBack on D and got some files and dirs. 60% were corrupted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover or "undelete" files that I accidentally deleted?](https://superuser.com/questions/449550/how-do-i-recover-or-undelete-files-that-i-accidentally-deleted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When files are deleted/cut from their original location, they are only marked as potential free space for writing.  The files are still there until they're overwritten by something else.

Here's some recovery software that helps in cases like these:

- Recouva (a freebie)
- Directory Snoop (trial, then paid)
- SpinRite (paid only)
- OnTrack EasyRecovery (trial, then paid)

The pasted copies...well, if those are corrupted, there are some recovery tools that can help, depending on the filetype and damage done to the file.

- DocRepair
- OfficeRecover

Comment: Spinrite does not recover deleted data, it only recovers bad sectors on the hard drive that contain data that has not been deleted. It works below the file system level.

Comment: Force Flow: Thanks for the software list. I tried GDB on D and got some files, however a lot of them were damaged. I suppose they've been overwritten with other files.