# how to recover files deleted by "Cutting" in windows 7-Pro

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

how to recover files deleted by "Cutting" in windows 7-Pro

I just did the silliest thing a few minutes ago!

I had a folder on my Win7 pro machine that had all my work (C# code in Visual Studio) for a couple of days. I wanted to move the draft to a more organized place. I cut all the files, deleted the source directory on my desktop and BAMMMM!!!! All my files were gone! I windows could not paste them, (because it cannot find the source) and "Undo"ing the rename did not help! :(

Since the files were on C:\ I bet its really hard to recover them, if all possible. Is there a trick somewhere in the windows? I am reluctant to use a recovery software [as suggested here (which by the way is not exactly the same problem)](https://superuser.com/questions/177728/how-to-recover-moved-cut-files-from-a-disk) (they are not free and the last time I used one, it took almost a day, I can re-write my code in probably few hours!)

**RESULT:**
After an hour, I decided to re-write my code but, @Stephen pointed out a really good thing to try.

Also, @FrankThomas, suggested a few recovery programs. I tried EaseUS, which recovered a lot of files! maybe if I would let it run for the rest of the day, it would recover my code, but it would mean that basically I had to stop working for the rest of the day.

***IF SomeThing Like This Happened To you***:

Try windows restore option first, by clicking in the folder, choosing properties and navigating to "Previous Versions" tab. If you are lucky, you can recover your stuff using that.

If it did not help, turn off your pc, move your HDD to another computer and then use recovery program on the other PC, *or* download a *portable* version of the file, put it on a USB disc and try recovering your stuff.

Comment: I think I'm S.O.L, right? because even visiting this website could have overwritten those files.

Comment: look at online recovery tools like Recuva or Easus or Glary recovery. they shoudl be reasonably quick. Failing that, fall back on offline tools like photorec. unless your drive is quite full, it is likely that the data has not yet been overwritten, but who knows...

Comment: Yes, you are right about the fate of deleted files in C partition. You would have removed the drive once you did it. I think it is the only way because the files are on the C partition(you know that very well, then why didn't you pull out the HDD?). I can't tell whether you have a chance, but you can try. Remove the HDD, attach it to another PC, run a program for recovery( I do not know any other programs other than TuneUp Utilities, of-course it is paid-only). Remember: **Do not use the drive anymore**

Comment: Aren't the "deleted" source files in your Recycle Bin? Or did you empty that?

Comment: @BigChris, they were not in the recycle bin although I never emptied it!

Comment: @FrankThomas, thanks for the tip. EaseUs recovered a lot of files! even from the previous user of the PC! but not those exact ones that were deleted!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover or "undelete" files that I accidentally deleted?](https://superuser.com/questions/449550/how-do-i-recover-or-undelete-files-that-i-accidentally-deleted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 makes auto backups of all its directories.  It's a long shot because you deleted the child directory rather than just the files but it's possible that if you right click inside the parent directory, choose properties then the previous versions tab.  It might be able to restore from that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I never thought of how useful this option is. It recovered the parent directory but not the files in it!

Comment: @fetah - So why did you accept the answer if it didn't restore the files?

Comment: @Ramhound: among all the suggested options it helped more!

Comment: @fetah - Your update to your question sounds more of like a self-answer then an update to the question.  Question(s) really should not have the answer contained within them.