# Is it possible to know filename after moving it?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, storage

I know that when you delete a file, you can still recover it until such time it's overwritten and can't be recovered(I know this is a oversimplification of what actually happens).

However, is it possible to recover a file or know what file used to occupy a folder after it's been **moved**? What I mean is, suppose I had a document called `work.doc` in my Documents folder, now I move that `.doc` file to my portable drive. If someone else comes along, can they run a piece of software to know what file used to occupy my documents folder, and see `work.doc`?

I know a person can see the recently opened files from the start menu or windows explorer, but if those were cleared, or I had that feature turned off, can a piece of software **know what was** there? Worse, could they possibly open it?

Comment: I think that this is related: [How to recover moved (cut) files from a disk?](https://superuser.com/a/177744/703240)
`When files are deleted/cut from their original location, they are only marked as potential free space for writing. The files are still there until they're overwritten by something else.`

Comment: Yes, because MOVE is actually a short term for two different steps: COPY, and DELETE in most cases. File recovery programs will find files that have been moved in the same way they find files that have been deleted directly.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens on all file systems, but on some the directory entry is flagged as free by putting a null in the first name byte, so until that entry is reused the name is recoverable, minus the first character: in your case the name would be `?ork.doc`, with`?` an unknown character. The reuse of the space that the file occupied is independent of the reuse of the directory entry.